# Is there a way to use cruise control without your foot becoming fatigued?

Tags: driving, automobiles

I was driving for 4 hours earlier and I set cruise control and pretty much don't need to do anything. For my left foot, there is a place to rest it in the footwell so no problem, but for the right foot no such thing exists.

Therefore I end up basically resting my foot on the accelerator without pressing down, which is pretty much the same as heel on the floor and lifting my foot up pretty hard. Maybe it's because I'm quite tall but my foot starts to ache after a while but there isn't anywhere else to put it unless I literally put it flat on the floor sideways (my knees would hit the steering wheel if it were straight) but that would prevent me from braking quickly.

Is there some simple mechanic of the car that I am missing that would make it more comfortable for a long journey?

Comment: In what way is this question specific to the UK (as indicated by the tag)?

Comment: @chirlu Because outside the UK the issue would not affect his right foot, it would affect his left foot. Sorry, could not help it :-D.

Comment: Nothing, that is why I edited the tags to something more fitting.

Comment: @SJuan76: It's not even true, of course - both right-hand and left-hand drive cars have the accelerator on the right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to drive a car, not about travel within the scope of this site. (Yes, cars are used for travel but not all travelling is on-topic, here.)

Comment: Oh sorry I put UK because our cars are smaller than the US and we drive manual cars not automatic if that makes a difference

Comment: @David domestic travel, or even your daily commute, is on-topic here.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm This isn't a question about travel: it's a question about how to operate a piece of machinery. And we've generally taken the attitude that anything in one's ordinary day-to-day life (e.g., one's daily commute) is _not_ on-topic, here. The [help] does indeed mention domestic travel but says nothing to hint that a regular commute is on-topic.

Comment: @David https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/is-commuting-on-topic

Comment: @AndrewGrimm OK. But this isn't a question even about commuting. It's a question about how to drive a car.

Comment: It's a question about a problem specific to travelling a long distance, perhaps take your comments to meta though as comments are not for extended discussion, or just flag to close.

Answer (score 7):

Two things come to my mind:

1. Too small car: if you're tall, the car may simply not be big enough for you; I always rest my right foot on the floor and have driven for 4+ hours without experiencing any noticeable inconveniences. You could also try driving SUV since they tend to higher chairs, which gives you more space between knees and floor.
2. Wrong sitting position: if you're sitting too close the pedals, you'll naturally not have enough space left.

Comment: Thanks I will try moving my seat back but I think it's already as far back as it goes.

Comment: @SLC That's good evidence that you may be driving a car that is too small for your body size.

Answer (score 1):

I am 6' 2' (188 cm) tall and drive several vehicles with cruise control:  a Subaru Outback and a Honda Insight.  The Insight definitely has limited leg space.

For light traffic conditions, it is usually safe to put the right foot on the floor.  Often I cross my legs for a few minutes every once in a while which is a very comfortable contrast to feet on the pedals.  If emergency stop conditions occur, both feet are needed pronto:  left for the clutch pedal and right for the brake pedal.  Starting from legs crossed on the floor, a reaction couldn't be much more than 0.25 seconds since there is no real weight on the feet.  If driving conditions deteriorate, I move my feet close to the pedals defensively.

In moderate or heavier traffic conditions where braking is much more likely, I rest the outside edge of my shoes on the walls beside the pedals.  At least on my vehicles, this is quite comfortable. Alas, I once drove a (forgotten) rental vehicle where there was no good place to do so for the right foot.

Comment: Hmm if you can cross your legs then your car is definitely quite big. Perhaps I will see if I can put my seat back

Comment: @wallyk In heavier traffic, it's highly recommended *not* to use cruise control.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie:  Agreed.  But some heavier traffic is predictable enough that it is reasonably safe to use cruise control but on an instant's notice to cancel it.

Comment: @wallyk It's those unpredictable moments, no matter how unlikely they are, that elevate your risk.  Maintain a significant following distance if you insist on the practice - longer than would be necessary if you were actively using your pedals.